# Show/hide all tooltips at once in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layers, tooltip

I use a `for` loop to add tooltips to my Leaflet map by reading the lat and lon coordinates from a .txt file.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   ...

   L.tooltip({
             permanent: true,
             direction: 'auto',
             className: 'my-label'
           })
         .setContent("Hello")
         .setLatLng([lat,lon])
         .addTo(map);
    ...
    })
```

I would like to put the tooltips on their own layer in order to make them visible or invisible by clicking on the layer check box in the layers panel (see `L.control.layers`)

How can I put all tooltips on a specific layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply create a layer group and instead of adding tooltips directly to the map, add them to the layer group. You can then add this layer group to layer control as an overlay.

```
var tooltipLayer = L.layerGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  ...
  L.tooltip({
    permanent: true,
    direction: 'auto',
    className: 'my-label'
  })
  .setContent("Hello")
  .setLatLng([lat,lon])
  .addTo(tooltipLayer);
  ...
});
```